# Binding DataTable to Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datatable, repeater

I have tried every combination of articles online I can find, and am pulling my hair out at this point. The below code does not seem to even attempt the databind.. when the "throw exception" line is not commented, it does not throw the exception.

I have tried just passing the DataTable IEnumerable and not the datatable/datarows, but I get "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a property with the name 'dateCompleted'."

Any kind of help would be appreciated...

C#

```
protected void runReportForUser(Guid UserID)
    {
        pnCard.Visible = true;
        pnNoPoints.Visible = false;

        using (var db = new db())
        {
            // scorecard logic

            var u = userProfile.get(UserID);

            var t = db.Database.SqlQuery<DataTable>("exec ReturnEntities '" + u.userID + "'").FirstOrDefault();
            //rptEvents.DataSource = t.ToArray()[0];

            rptEvents.DataSource = t.Rows;
            //rptEvents.DataSource = t;   

            rptEvents.DataBind();

        }
    }


protected void rptEvents_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            //throw new Exception("Test")
            DataRow dr = (DataRow)e.Item.DataItem;

            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDate")).Text = dr[0].ToString();
            //((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDate")).Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "dateCompleted").ToString();
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCategory")).Text = dr[1].ToString();
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName")).Text = dr[2].ToString();
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPointsValue")).Text = dr[3].ToString();

        }
    }
```

ASPX:

```
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Points Earned</th>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptEvents" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptEvents_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="trEvents" runat="server">
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblPointsValue" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
```

Comment: Most likely the if statement does not match? How about if you insert a statement before the if statement?

Comment: I commented out the if statement to test that and it still produced the same results.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? I'm curious what the count of the t.Rows is before you do the DataBind.

Comment: Depending on what I try I either get the correct number of rows or 0. That 0 is probably why the code isn't running in the data bind, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out after a lot of trying different things. I ended up having to make it a list of a user defined class which matched the table structure. It looks like either way of binding works below.

Here it is in case it helps someone:

```
protected void runReportForUser(Guid UserID)
    {
        pnCard.Visible = true;
        pnNoPoints.Visible = false;

        using (var db = new db())
        {
            // scorecard logic

            var u = userProfile.get(UserID);

            var t = db.Database.SqlQuery<EntityHistory>("exec dbo.ReturnEntities '" + u.userID.ToString() + "'");
            List<EntityHistory> EntityList = t.ToList<EntityHistory>();
            rptEvents.DataSource = EntityList;
            rptEvents.DataBind();

        }
    }

protected void rptEvents_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
        EntityHistory EH = (EntityHistory)e.Item.DataItem;
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDate")).Text = EH.dateCompleted;
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCategory")).Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Category").ToString();
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName")).Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Name").ToString();
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPointsValue")).Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "MaxPointsEach").ToString();
        }
    }

public class EntityHistory
{
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public String dateCompleted {get;set;}
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 MaxPointsEach { get; set; }
}
```